# change a row template in silverlight datagrid for a particular row

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

i have a datagrid with 10 rows. The columns are all of type textbox . But only for the 7th row i want the column template to be combobox instead of textbox. can this be done ?? Any examples ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by having both textbox and combox in the celltemplate and Hide combox for all other rows except 7th row and Hide textbox for 7th row.